# how tocreate records in sugarcrmCE 6.5 custom subpanel using rest api

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

i have created record using REST API for account module, now i want to add all related record for the sub-panel like payment information of an account using REST API which is provided by sugarCRM, and want to have one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

For related record sugarcrm basically maintaining separate table 
for example

For product module and inventory module ( one - many relationship ) it will maintain table some thing like below .

> aos_products_i_inventory_1_c

so if we want to add related records , we can map the id of product and inventory in this table .

so , basically you need to have a RestApi Call for inserting ( mapping ) account id and payment id in your relation ship table .

you can search for which method to use from documentation

[Rest Methods call documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/05_Method_Calls/)

And if the no method suites your requirement then you can create you own methods for RestApi according to your needs , under **Sugarcrm/service/core/SugarWebServiceImpl.php** .

consider this example of custom method for Api which will return the product price from ( product module ) and available count from ( inventory module) based on product.

```
function get_inventory_count_Productprice($session, $model_number){

$GLOBALS['log']->info('Begin: SugarWebServiceImpl->get_count_relation');
$error = new SoapError();
// check the access for particular sesstion 
if (!self::$helperObject->checkSessionAndModuleAccess($session, 'invalid_session', '', '', '', $error)) {
    $error->set_error('invalid_login');
    $GLOBALS['log']->info('End: SugarWebServiceImpl->get_available_modules');
    return;
} // if
$qur = "SELECT price,id FROM aos_products where part_number='".$model_number."' AND deleted=0 LIMIT 0,1";
$res = $GLOBALS['db']->query($qur);
$row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($res);

$focus = BeanFactory::getBean('AOS_Products', $row['id']);      //Retrieve bean
$inventory = $focus->get_linked_beans('aos_products_i_inventory_1','i_inventory');  // loading relation ship
$count = 0 ;
foreach ($inventory as $product) {
    if($product->status=='available'){
        $count++;
    }
}
$GLOBALS['log']->info('End: SugarWebServiceImpl->get_count_relation');
return array(
    'price' => $row['price'],
    'count' => $count,
    );

}
```

i hope this will help you  .